# Flash movie only renders in Chrome, not WebBrowser control?

Tags: vb.net, video, vector, webbrowser-control

I'm getting an output message (`Vector smash protection is enabled`) in the debugging output window (Visual Studio) when I navigate to [this URL](http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2boiq5) with a `WebBrowser`.

The URL redirects to an embedded video player from [Dailymotion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dailymotion). It should look like this :

[image: Image of correctly running URL]

But it looks like this :

[image]

What this message means? Why do I have a black screen (the video isn't shown)? How to fix it?

**Edit :** You can see all the code in the last screenshot...

Comment: Could you post all code that replicates this?

Comment: All the code is in the last screenshot !

Answer (score 2):

I noticed something similar myself.
I got the following when installing python webbrowser:

Vector smash protection is enabled.
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.6) (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

I am convinced that it is to prevent a type of denial of service attack, just released in Java 1.7, with no fanfare.
see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html
and
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html

Edit 1:

As my issue was coming from the pdf viewer `atril`, I approached the writers of the program and they have informed me that the `Vector smash protection is enabled` message is being issued by Webkit. Atril added a new epub backend to their code and it uses Webkit.
A cursory search suggests that it is a defence against a stack smash or heap spraying attack, although don't hold me to it.
The reason that this message seems to be popping up across browsers, viewers and indeed operating systems, appears to be directly related to how many programs now use webkit under the hood, as it were.
Here are 2 lists of code making use of webkit:

http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/ApplicationsGtk
http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Applications%20using%20WebKit

As usual, if in doubt, your own research may prove more effective than mine but I for one am much happier about the message, now that I know what it is.
Should I come across anything else germane, I'll edit this post.

Comment: Sorry no, I have been unable to find where the change was made. Looking up the diff file between the current version and the previous one, all I get is: Changes: 
 openjdk-7 (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1) trusty-security; urgency=medium
 .
   * Backport to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: I think it's not because of Java, but because of the website. I say this because my code has stopped working a few days ago and I haven't updated Java... Dailymotion has certainly done something... (I'm talking about the website I wanna display).

Comment: So far I have trawled through java 1.7, firefox 40, adblock and chromium and still found nothing. The reason that I believe it to be java, is that java would be the common denominator. I came across the reference just loading python's webbrowser function which suggests that no internet connection was involved at all. It's something local that has changed.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the comments :D If I find a solution, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I have tracked down where my message is from, /usr/bin/atril the Mate pdf viewer and that has update on the 8th August, probably when I upgraded to mint 17.2, so the plot thickens

Answer (score 1):

The message "Vector smash protection is enabled." is emitted by Flash.ocx (you can find it in the DLL). It's likely related to this security mitigation: http://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2015/07/significant-flash-exploit-mitigations_16.html

Comment: A `solution` implies a `problem`. What's the problem you're having? The message is harmless and should be ignored.

Comment: My problem is that, like in the last screenshot, my embedded video isn't shown (black screen), while in Google Chrome it works (see the first screenshot)...

Comment: The problem is likely related to a problem where Flash isn't rendering due to DirectX issues. If you load the content in IE, does it render? Is your app compiled for AnyCPU or just x86?

Comment: The problem is that this message is appearing frequently/regularly on my OS X Terminal application and fouling the display.

Comment: It's unlikely that anyone other than Adobe can suppress this message, unless you're willing to edit the binary yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with this problem using the chrome options and creating a desired capabilities but first of all you need to consider:

1: the value you should to put in 'user-data-dir' is the same you can find out in the route chrome://version/ in Google Chrome. Let me explain that with a picture (at the end of this answer).

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/Users/YourUser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

​And afterward you need to add this options to your Driver:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

So, this is the best way to make request to a page that has **Vector smash protection enabled**.

[image: user-data-dir value]

Answer (score -2):

Sorry but I can't spent time but the following was printed on my bash terminal.

```
Vector smash protection is enabled.
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_va_gl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_va_gl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_va_gl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
...
```